# How can I resolve unique constraint errors?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my code.

```
declare
    v1 tblsubject.subjectseq%type;
    v2 tblteam.teamname%type;
    cursor vcursor is
        select distinct t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
        from tblteam t1
                 inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
                 inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
                 inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
                 inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
                 inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ;
begin
    open vcursor;
    loop
        fetch vcursor into v1, v2;
        insert into tblproject
        select rownum, t5.SUBJECTNAME || 'project', T3.SUBJECTEND, t1.TEAMSEQ
from tblteam t1
         inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
         inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
         inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ
where (v1, v2) in (
    select distinct t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
    from tblteam t1
             inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
             inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
             inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
             inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
             inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ);
        exit when vcursor%notfound;
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE(v1);
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE(v2);
    end loop;
end;
```

The table structure for the 14th row in question is:

```
create table TBLPROJECT
(
    PROJECTSEQ NUMBER not null
        constraint TBLPROJECT_PK
        primary key,
    PROJECTREGIST VARCHAR2(300),
    PROJECTSUBMITDATE DATE,
    TEAMSEQ NUMBER
)
```

Execute a PL/SQL statement

```
[2021-06-03 20:22:44] [23000][1]
[2021-06-03 20:22:44] ORA-00001: unique constraint (SIST2.TBLPROJECT_PK) violated
[2021-06-03 20:22:44] ORA-06512: at line 16
[2021-06-03 20:22:44] Position: 0
```

The above error appears.

I don't have any code that violates the integrity constraint and I'm not sure how to fix this.

best regards

Comment: Well, Oracle disagrees with you that your code violates the integrity constraint.  I don't quite follow what you are trying to do but populating the primary key with `rownum` in a loop is unlikely to work.  Each query would start with a `rownum` of 1 so if the `insert` tries to insert rows in multiple iterations of the loop, you'd violate the constraint by trying to insert multiple rows with a primary key value of 1.  Normally, you'd use a sequence to populate a primary key and select the `nextval` of the sequence in the `insert` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop exit condition is in the wrong place; it should be:

```
    loop
        fetch vcursor into v1, v2;
        exit when vcursor%notfound;
        insert into tblproject
        ...
```

At the moment the last successful fetch causes an insert; then you fetch again which finds no more data, but you insert anyway based on the last-fetched values, which will be a duplicate.

You probably want the `dbms_output` calls before the insert too, so you can at least debug the value causing the insert to fail.

However, using `rownum` also looks like it will cause duplicates as that will repeat values for each iteration of the loop. You can see that [in this db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca1c18ad7c2f8d18abf47efeab57bfd7); each time round the loop you get the same `rn` value (as an alias for `rownum`). When it tries to insert that instead of just printing the values it attempts to insert two rows with the same PK value - which causes the constraint error.

That PK value should perhaps be taken from a sequence (or make it an identity column) but it depends why you are doing it like that now.

And this probably doesn't need PL/SQL at all; but rewriting as a single insert statement is rather out of scope.

Comment: table is empty... and exit when is below the fetch but it's not solved

Comment: Which table is empty - the target table when you start? That doesn't matter if it's the inserts in your code that are duplicates. As me and Justin both said, using `rownum` is going to cause duplicates; the second time round the loop you will get `rownum` values starting from 1 again, which will immediately be a duplicate PK.